# Image browser widget on Google Colab

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I want to run an image browser widget on Google Colab that would allow me to view slices on an MRI volume.

I'm guessting [that this is not currently supported](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/tree/master/google/colab/widgets). Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colab has its own widget stuff. Here's how to do an image browser in Colab.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qUR-fR_G7QVga87-TZmn18RWukBkTX4S